# How to get kube-ps1 to work in Wrap terminal?

Tags: kubernetes, zsh, oh-my-zsh, warp-terminal

I'm trying to move from [iterm2](https://iterm2.com/) to [warp](https://www.warp.dev/), but one thing that I can't get working, which is quite crucial for me, is the [kube-ps1](https://github.com/jonmosco/kube-ps1) project. What it does is to make the current Kubernetes context visible at the prompt like this:

[image]

In iterm2, this indicates that I'm in the "prod" Kubernetes context. I'm using Oh My Zsh in iterm2, and just installed it using the docs on the page:

```
brew install kube-ps1
```

I've then done the following since I'm using zsh (ohmyzsh):

```
plugins=(
  kube-ps1
)

PROMPT='$(kube_ps1)'$PROMPT # or RPROMPT='$(kube_ps1)'
```

In iterm2, it now works correctly (after running `kubeon`) and I can see the kubernetes context in the prompt, but it doens't seem to work in Warp.

I've also tried this:

```
$ source /opt/homebrew/Cellar/kube-ps1/0.8.0/share/kube-ps1.sh
PROMPT='$(kube_ps1)'$PROMPT # or RPROMPT='$(kube_ps1)'
```

But I still doesn't work. How I can get kube-ps1 to work in Warp?

Comment: oh-my-zsh plugins are unsupported https://docs.warp.dev/help/known-issues#list-of-incompatible-tools

Comment: Oh, I didn't know this, thank you. I'd love to get this working though so I'm hoping for an answer/workaround.